# SwiftUI Navigation and status bar clash in color/transparency when inside TabView

Tags: ios, swiftui

My app consists of a few views across a few different tabs inside a `TabView`. These views create their own `NavigationView`s. Unfortunately the existence of the `TabView` is causing their colors and transparency to clash with the app's status bar, which is no longer in line with the navigation bar.

This is easily reproduced in a sample app using the following code.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavView()
        }
    }
}

struct NavView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { _ in
                    Section(header: Text("Foo")) {
                        Text("Bar")
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("Foobar")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the grouped list style to make the styling changes more apparent, but it's the same with the default style.

Is there a SwiftUI API to access the status bar styling? Or possibly some other workaround?

[image: large navigation bar screenshot]

[image: inline navigation bar screenshot]

Comment: I used `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` on my `TabView`, so the colour of `NavigationView` or anything else gets displayed. Also I think `NavigationView` gets the right insets again, because it does not messes up my navigation bat title top offset.

Comment: Fantastic, that does the trick. Thank you! I'd love to mark it as the solution if you put it in an answer 

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per Apple's documentation, `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(_:)` should be applied to `TabView`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vsplitview/3288813-edgesignoringsafearea

> Extends the view out of the safe area on the specified edges.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavView()
        } // .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) no longer necessary as of iOS 13.4
    }
}
```

NOTE: It appears Apple changed the default behavior and this is no longer necessary with iOS 13.4.

Comment: This is not working on iPhone 11 simulator (XCode 11.4)

Comment: This bugs. The navigation view slides underneath the notch

Comment: It appears Apple changed the default behavior and this is no longer necessary with iOS 13.4.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it stopped working properly for me. The situation was it was working without `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(_:)` applied just for the simulator but not a device. And vice versa when it is applied to it.

Created a little modifier to fix it.

```
struct EdgeIgnoringSafeAreaModifier: ViewModifier {

    var edges: Edge.Set

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
        return content
        #else
        return content.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(self.edges)
        #endif
    }
}

extension View {
    func edgeIgnoringSafeAreaForDevice(_ edges: Edge.Set) -> some View {
        self.modifier(EdgeIgnoringSafeAreaModifier(edges: edges))
    }
}
```